# C++ Eigen: dereferencing an InnerIterator

Tags: eigen, eigen3

`Matrix<T, Dynamic, Dynamic>::InnerIterator` doesn't seem to use the standard way (`operator *`) to dereference it.

It has a member function `value()`.

I am rather surprised, as this would not interface well with third party algorithms, like STL algorithms.

Why it doesn't declare `operator *`? Even worse is that `value()` does not return by reference, so you can't change the underlying value of the pointed element. What is the proper way to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because most of the times, the value alone in useless without the respective inner/row/column indices, as returned by `index()/row()/col()`. In other cases, you only care about the indices. Anyway, you can easily write a little wrapper to make it compatible with STL if needed.

Finally, if you want to modify the value, there is a `valueRef()` method returning by non const reference.